# What on earth is [step] tag, it's not synonymous with [increment], should it be redefined?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

This question is what to do with the current incarnation of the tag [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/step), see below.

- First off, the tag [increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/increment) is good and useful, and it has 2.7K hits. (In some of those 'increment' is used as a verb, and sometimes as a noun. That's fine. Btw, 'increment' means 'add fixed value', not necessarily one, not necessarily positive, not necessarily integer, although +1 is obviously the most common choice.)
- the term 'increment' is generally synonymous with [increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/increment) (IME, AFAIK) for loop-constructs, ranges, counters, iterators,  in most programming languages I've seen. (I'm sure there are a few exception corner-cases out there, but I believe this is generally true across languages).
- However [back in the mists of 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5747572/revisions) somehow a tag [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/step) got created, named after some fairly obscure ISO protocol (for manufacturing/CAD, not even software per se). Topic wiki:

> *STEP (Standard for the Exchange of Product data), otherwise known as*
>   *ISO 10303, provides a mechanism to describe product data throughout*
>   *the life cycle of a product, independent from any particular system.*

- [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/step) only has 90 hits, and at first glance only 21(!) of those are relevant to its meaning [cad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cad)
- so, 77% of its use is misapplications by users who (reasonably) expect it to mean something similar to [increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/increment), and have something to do with for/while-loops, ranges, generators etc.

Questions:

1. **Presumably we should remove the current 'ISO 10303' definition of [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/step)? and untag the CAD uses.**

   - that small community can continue to use plaintext search; the string [ISO 10303](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ISO+10303)
     is trivially easy to find, even without quotes. Ditto '.STP file'.
2. **Next, what do we actually do with tag [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/step)?**

   - alias it to [increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/increment)? or else what?
3. last, and not very controversially, **the topic wiki for [increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/increment) should be changed** from *"Adding one to the value of a variable, generally with the use of an increment operator."* to something like *"Adding one (or other fixed value) to the value of a variable."* I'd remove the *"generally with the use of an increment operator"* part because some languages don't have a `+=` or `incr()` operator, and it really doesn't matter how you do it

   - (C/C++ people you know exactly what I mean, don't start lecturing us about side-effects in macro expansion in imperative languages where standards don't define order-of-evaluation for prefix/postfix `++` etc. This is why you don't get invited to parties :) Just keep it simple.)

(PS: this question is probably fodder for highly puntastic titles, and names of pop songs over many decades. Have at it, kids. I'm sure you'll take great *strides*.)

Comment: [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3015252%20[step]%20is:answer) and [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:149956%20[step]%20is:answer) are the subject experts.  If you are going to make hard for them to share their knowledge then you need to provide a better alternative.

Comment: @HansPassant you're missing my point: should an obscure ISO manufacturing protocol with at most 21(!) legitimate uses even get its own tag? Worse still, thereby eclipsing the far more common meaning that 99.999% of programmers would (wrongly) assume the tag had. Plaintext search is the better alternative, for that case. The string [ISO 10303](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ISO+10303) is trivially easy to find, even without quotes. So, zero demonstrated need for a tag.

Comment: Obscurity has never been a good reason to destroy a tag.  Far from it, such a tag is essential to bring subject experts to the obscure topic.  They don't go searching for them, the machine puts these questions on the "Interesting" page automatically.  That they have to deal with clumsy tagging from users that don't read the wiki popup is not much of a problem with such a low volume.

Comment: @smci How do you define obscure? STEP files are quite common in industrial manufacturing and CAD. Also a number of simulation tools for civil engineering uses them. Being misused is not a good reason to remove a otherwise valid tag.

Comment: Wait, increment is a "good tag"? Why? STEP is at least something unique to software development, but increment?

Comment: Why not create an `iso-10303` tag and have `step` as a synonym. Then the master tag will be unambiguous. Presumably all two of the experts are cognizant of the ISO standard and will be happy to change their favorite tags?